# After Effects CS4 shows installed while installing Creative Suite 4

Tags: windows-xp, adobe-after-effects, adobe-creative-suite

I recently needed to reinstall Windows XP, but I didn't perform a clean install with formatting the partition, but I installed on the partition without formatting, and it only deleted the windows files. Now I am trying to install Adobe Creative Suite 4: Master Collection, but I am unable to install AE with it because it shows it is still installed. I check the Add or Remove Programs, and also looked for the folder on Program Files, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You just run some program from creative suite and deactivate to not lose your license.

You can use the [CS Cleaner tool](http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cscleanertool.html), which will clean up the installations and allow you to install again.

Comment: Why thank you. I am downloading right now, will post the results later to inform anyone who is having the same issue.